# Using annotations (with AOP?) to inject fields (with getters and setters) into POJO

Tags: java, annotations, pojo, aop

Is it possible to decorate POJOs with fields and getters+setters, with annotations? Let's say I have a class like **edited**:

```
public abstract class Human { //to be extended by classes like Male, Female
    private String name;
    private String identificationNumber;
    private String mailingAddress;

    public void setName(String name) {...}
    public String getName() {...}

    public void setIdentificationNumber(String number) {...}
    public String getIdentificationNumber() {...}

    public void setMailingAddress(String address) {...}
    public String getMailingAddress() {...}
}
```

and I also have another class like **edited**:

```
public abstract class Animal { //to be extended by classes like Dog, or Wolf
    private String name;
    private String furColor;
    private String ferocityIndex;

    public void setName(String name) {...}
    public String getName() {...}

    public void setFurColor(String color) {...}
    public String getFurColor() {...}

    public void setFerocityIndex(String index) {...}
    public String getFerocityIndex() {...}
}
```

If there's a scenario where I need to create a Werewolf (hybrid of Human and Animal), essentially I need to "extend" both classes. I already understand that I could've used interfaces for both abstract classes, but that would mean re-implementing the getters and setters, and having the field implementation replicated to all implementing class.

I want to be able to define both Human and Animal as annotations, so the Werewolf class can look like:

```
@Human
@Animal
public class Werewolf {
}
```

and I should be able to see the getters and setters from the main class like:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Werewolf jonathan = new Werewolf();
    jonathan.getName();
    //should be Werewolf's not Human's implementation or Animal implementations
    //if jonathan has a different animal name, @Animal should implement animalName, not name
    jonathan.getFerocityIndex(); //should be here
    jonathan.getIdentificationNumber(); //should also be here
}
```

My project currently uses spring, so Spring AOP is not out of the question as long as someone can point me in the right direction if this is at all possible or there is already a library for this. Because I think from certain perspective, Werewolf has Human aspect and an Animal aspect, CMIIW.

In short: is there anyway for me to inject a set of fields with getter+setters (defined by the annotation?), into the annotated class, during compile time?

**Edited for additional detail**:

- Both `@Animal` and `@Human` defines a field of `name`. Which when injected into `Werewolf` should become his (it's?) `name`.
- The answer from [user2693476](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2693476/user2693476) provides composition of `IHuman` and `IAnimal` will make the `name` field inconsistent, is it human's or animal's?
- My goal is for the `@Human` and `@Animal` to tell the annotated `Werewolf` class that: ***I hereby give you these fields as your own***. So, in a way: code templating. Using reflection it would be possible for me to detect duplicated Fields of `name` and apply only once, or to throw `RuntimeException`. But I don't know yet how to inject codes into the `Werewolf` class.

-Jonathan

Answer (score 0):

The purpose for Spring AOP is to inject some common codes which is repeating in lots of methods, so that you only need to define those common codes in a method, and you can use it everywhere in your program, and this is not suitable to apply in your problem. 
In your case, this looks more like OO design problem, as your Werewolf needs to share both the properties in human and animal, you could define two more interface for Human and Animal:

```
public interface IHuman{ //implemented by Human and Werewolf
  public void setIdentificationNumber(String number);
  public String getIdentificationNumber();
  public void setMailingAddress(String address);
  public String getMailingAddress();
}

public interface IAnimal { //implemented by Animal and Werewolf
  public void setFurColor(String color);
  public String getFurColor() {...}

  public void setFerocityIndex(String index);
  public String getFerocityIndex();
}
```

and in your Werewolf class, you can use the benefit of Composition to help you to realize your idea.

```
public class Werewolf implements IHuman, IAnimal{
    private IHuman human;
    private IAnimal animal;

    //create getter and setter for human and animal to assign the concrete implemented Human    and Animal instance to Werewolf
    ...
  //and you can define all your unimplemented methods in this way
  public void setIdentificationNumber(String number){
      this.human.setIdentificationNumber(number);
  }

  public String getIdentificationNumber(){
      return this.human.getIdentificationNumber();
  }

  public void setMailingAddress(String address){
      this.human.setMailingAddress(address);
  }

  public String getMailingAddress(){
      return this.human.getMailingAddress();
  }

  public void setFurColor(String color){
      this.animal.setFurColor(color);
  }
  public String getFurColor() {
      return this.animal.getFurColor();
  }

  public void setFerocityIndex(String index){
     this.animal.setFerocityIndex(index);
  }
  public String getFerocityIndex(){
     return this.animal.getFerocityIndex();
  }

}
```

Comment: I have already tried composition pattern, but it does not address duplication of fields, it will make the `Werewolf` class undecided on which field it needs to get+set from. See my edit above. Thank you.

Comment: I feel it's not necessary to implements/extends getter and setters, as those methods are only for accessing private fields. Doing this is actually tightly coupled your sub-class with your super-classes. Most of time best practice is just extending the metheds presenting the class behaviors. And as you already get the access to the attributes in Animal and Human in your werewolf class, you could simply define some methods like getAnimalName and getHumanName to access those duplicated fields

Answer (score 0):

You seem to look for a workaround to multiple inheritance in Java using annotations. Check the @Delegate annotation of the Lombock project. If you don't like it, you should have a look at the Annotation Processing Tool for Java and write your own annotations. Beware of possible drawbacks of such solutions (IDE support, documentation, readability for the new contributers...).